# Disecting WPF Path, Data Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Consider the following piece of code:

```
<Path x:Name="CheckMark" Stroke="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:PropertyGrid}, ResourceId=GlyphBrush}}" StrokeThickness="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Data="M 0 0 L 13 13 M 0 13 L 13 0 M 20 20" />
```

I know that, the part inside Data draws a cross, but I don't understand the syntax of it. It's probably like Old School QBasic Draw commands. Can someone explain to me, why it draws a **Cross**.

And for future reference, could someone point me to resources where I can get explanation on the commands to Draw `Paths`.

Comment: `Data="M 0 0 L 13 13 M 0 13 L 13 0 M 20 20"` This basically does the following: Moves cursor to 0, 0. Draws a line from there to 13, 13, then sets the cursor to 0, 13 and draws a line from there to 13,0 and finally the last M just sets the cursor to 20,20 which really has no effect. So the first line will be a ` \ ` and the second line is ` / `. Put them on top of eachother and you have an X (cross)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided in the answer is dead.

Please use [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path.data.aspx) for the documentation of the general Path.Data property and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535793.aspx) for the "Move and Draw" command syntax as used in your example code.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294564%28v=Expression.10%29
this is wpf geometry, use expression blend to draw the path